# AjaxFileUpload Doesn't Display Correctly or Function: Mysterious Black Button

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I found AjaxFileUpload in the toolkit when searching for ways to upload multiple files.

1. I used NuGet to install.
2. Added `<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>` to the top of the page.
3. Ensured web.config has the reference:
   `<pages>
     <controls>
       <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
     </controls>
   </pages>`

Where I presume the the upload button should be, I get a black box, when I run the page.  The preview does show up correctly.

I did try it in a completely empty page (no master page or anything) and I get the same result.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="School_Scheduler_2.Associates.test" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload runAt="server" ID="multiUpload" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

## Answer Since My Account Is Too Noob to the Post Answer Myself

This explains it: https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27493

Long story short: The Ajax Tool Kit does not like the vanilla ScriptManager. It insists on using their own ToolkitScriptManager.

This causes havoc with my MasterPages (I put the script manager on there to save me from adding it everywhere), but at least I know now and can start scheming possible solutions.

Comment: Seems like a css problem. Do you get the same here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ajaxFileUpload/ajaxFileUpload.aspx?

Comment: It looks correct there.  That is the original sample that enticed me to try out the control.

Comment: I am pretty much using the vanilla CSS from the default master page.  Nothing fancy.  Also, my test page, which isn't part of a master page, shouldn't be impacted by any of my CSS anyway.

Comment: CSS would usually only break the appearance.  It does not function at all either.  I've tried drag and drop and clicking the mysterious black button.

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: I guess that's an obvious question to ask, and yet I was too rushed to even think of it.  Yes there is an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UI' of undefined.  I don't know what that implies, but gives me something to search for!

Comment: Tried changing the TagPrefix, as suggested here http://forums.asp.net/t/1931739.aspx, but no dice.

Comment: Do you have any other framework in your code? jQuery, Mootools? etc...

Comment: This explains it: https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27493

Long story short: The Ajax Tool Kit does not like the vanilla ScriptManager. It insists on using their own ToolkitScriptManager.

This causes havoc with my MasterPages (I put the script manager on there to save me from adding it everywhere), but at least I know now and can start scheming possible solutions.

Comment: I had read elsewhere that it is supposed to work with either ScriptManager... apparently not!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: It also DOES NOT WORK with the Toolkit Script Manager. I changed namespace names, added handers and controls to the web.config and what not, but I only get the stupid black box! This is boken!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div  align="center">
    <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,gif"
                        MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" OnUploadComplete="File_Upload"
                        Width="500px" />
```

Comment: Although the help is appreciated, answers should always have enough context to be *understood*. This is often only as much text as is in this comment, but it *is needed*.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but make sure to debug any javascript errors. Any errors will cause the described black button.

If you have any client side code that runs on OnClientUploadCompleteAll=, but fail to copy this code to a new page if you are copy/pasting the AjaxFileUpload control, you get a javascript error and it fails to render the control at this point, just leaving you with the black button.